# How Add jar file to eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to write a plugin in eclipse that sends active window title to a port when active window changes. For this purpose I have to add jna and jna-platform-win32 libraries to my plugin. This libraries add in compile time but when I want to use them in run time libraries not worked. How can I solve this problem in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the jars to the `Bundle-Classpath` in the plugin MANIFEST.MF and also include them in the 'build.properties' file so they are included in the plugin build.

To add to the `Bundle-Classpath` open the plugin.xml editor and go to the 'Runtime' tab. Add the jars to the 'Classpath' section (you should also have a '.' entry for your normal plugin classes).

The 'Build' tab of the plugin.xml editor updates the build.properties file so make sure the jars are checked in the Binary Build section.