# How to load a jar during plugin startup?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, java-15

I have a Eclipse plugin project. I have a scenario where I need to load a external jar during plugin start-up at runtime. I am using Java 15.

Comment: Why do you need to do this at startup time instead of using [the usual way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30118422/2711488)?

Comment: @Holger, we have a scenario where we are setting a custom encoding within Eclipse IDE. so we have a custom encoding jar need to be loaded at runtime which sets the custom encoding to Eclipse during startup. Hence we need the jar to loaded at startup.